# The Six-Edged Sword

Tags: cipher

Your friend buys a new ninja sword online, but when he receives the package it is shipped to "seltruTajniNtnatuMeganeeT" and contains this message written in the inside of the box:

> bggp tp fjcg pkgg kdta btlg oqkg pd ekjcu cd dcg tca teodsqpgsy cd ndbfqpgko j cgga pd vgkjmy ydq tkg pig kgngjvgk dm pijo jpgb ftkp ndbjcu oddc j lcdw ydq sjvg dc  dtl pkgg ndqkp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [cryptogram solver](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/cryptogram-solver.php), the message is revealed to be:

> MEET AT PINE TREE ROAD MAKE SURE TO BRING NO ONE AND ABSOLUTELY NO COMPUTERS I NEED TO VERIFY YOU ARE THE RECEIVER OF THIS ITEM PART COMING SOON I KNOW YOU LIVE ON OAK TREE COURT

I wouldn't follow the instructions, as it seems the post office has confused your friend for the

> Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles